# Correct way for calculating Phi (golden ratio)

Tags: golden-ratio

I've seen in some of the resources, that Phi is calculated in a way that the whole (=1) is divided into two parts:

---------------------**x**----------------------|---------**1-x**--------------

$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x}{1-x}\\1-x=x^2 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \rightarrow x^2+x-1=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\rightarrow x_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$

This will get the correct values for phi eg.:0.618... and -1.618...
But it doesnt work, if I switch the values like this:

---------------------**1-x**----------------------|---------**x**--------------

$\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1-x}{x}\\x=x^2-2x+1 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \rightarrow x^2-3x+1=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\rightarrow x_{1,2}=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$

Now, the wikipedia page gives [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Calculation) way and it works, but I wanted to ask what is wrong with the way I did it here because as I said, I've seen it quite frequently.
Thx

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your way. You just have to change the sign.

Comment: ok I give up. What sign are you talking about? (where?)

Comment: You want to calculate the length of the left side and you got $x_{1,2}=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now the length of the left side is $1-x=1-\frac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{2-3\mp \sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{-1\mp\sqrt{5}}{2}$. This is just the same as before (mod swapping the ordering/sign at $\sqrt{5}$)

Comment: yup thats it, I think that I got confused because the first version gives the phi and 1/phi directly as solution of the equation (because it involves 1/x at the left side). THX man

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the right result, but the $x$ in the first computation isn't the same number as the $x$ in the second one. Rather $x_{\rm second}$ should be $1-x_{\rm first}$, and indeed we have
$$ 1 - \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2} = \frac{3-\sqrt5}2 $$
and
$$ 1 - \frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2} = \frac{3+\sqrt5}2 $$